# DRF endpoint returns weirdly serialized object although it is fetch correctly in the view

Tags: django

So I'm using [Django REST auth](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#setting-the-authentication-scheme) and [dj-rest-auth](https://dj-rest-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) as authentication backend for my React app. In the view it seems that it grabs the correct instance of the logged in user, but it doesn't reflect that in the response. Also if I print fields of that instance it returns the wrong data, the serializer instance however looks like it holds the correct object to serialize...hm

```
# views.py

class UserDetail(APIView):
    """
    Retrieve a User instance
    """
    def get(self, request):
        print('Header Token: ' + str(request.META['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION']))
        print('request.user: ' + str(request.user))
        try:
            user_profile = UserProfile(user=request.user)
            print('user_profile: ' + str(user_profile))
            print('user_profile.company: ' + str(user_profile.company)). # Why is this none?
            serializer = UserProfileSerializer(user_profile)
            print('serializer: ' + str(serializer)) # looks like the instance is correct though..
            print('serializer.data: ' + str(serializer.data))
            return Response(serializer.data)
        except UserProfile.DoesNotExist:
            raise Http404
```

Returns

[image]

and Postman returns

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vzkZ2.png]

But the data should be:

[image]

```
# models.py

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    """
    Extends Base User via 1-1 for profile information
    """
    # Relations
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)

    # Roles
    is_ta = models.BooleanField(default=False)  # indicates if user is part of TA department

    def __str__(self):
        return F'{self.user.first_name} {self.user.last_name}'


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def update_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        UserProfile.objects.create(user=instance)
    instance.userprofile.save()
```

```
# serializers.py

class UserProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = '__all__'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are incorrectly fetching the `UserProfile` instance, instead of:

```
user_profile = UserProfile(user=request.user)
```

try:

```
user_profile = UserProfile.objects.get(user=request.user)
```

UPD:
In order to create a nested representation either set `depth` attribute in `Meta` of your serializer:

```
class UserProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = '__all__'
        depth = 1
```

or create a separate serializer for your related fields, e.g.:

```
class CompanySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Company
        fields = your_fields
```

and set the serializer as field:

```
class UserProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    company = CompanySerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = '__all__'
```

Comment: palmface... thanks! Now it returns "1" for the related fields though. How can I also return the data of those nested?